# Getting the frequency of categorical values in get dummies in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am implementing one hot encoding here on the data

```
Version  Cluster_Size     Hardware_type  
1.0.4     3              Aplha,Alpha,Aplha
1.0.2     3              Aplha,Beta,Aplha 
1.0.9     3              Aplha,Beta,Gama
```

after df['hardware_type'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ') I was able to get the data frame like this

```
Version  Cluster_Size     Hardware_type      Alpha   Beta   Gama
1.0.4     3              Alpha,Alpha,Alpha     1       0      0
1.0.2     3              Alpha,Beta,Alpha      1       1      0
1.0.9     3              Alpha,Beta,Gama       1       1      1
```

which is exactly what the one-hot encoding should do but I am trying to achieve something like this wherein the columns I can get the count of categorical values appearing in their respective cell.

```
Version  Cluster_Size     Hardware_type      Alpha   Beta   Gama
1.0.4     3              Alpha,Alpha,Alpha     3       0      0
1.0.2     3              Alpha,Beta,Alpha      2       1      0
1.0.9     3              Alpha,Beta,Gama       1       1      1
```

Is there a way to do something like this ?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) there is no information about counts.

So need another solutions - here is used `Counter` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import Counter
L = [Counter(x.split(',')) for x in df['Hardware_type']]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
  Version  Cluster_Size      Hardware_type  Alpha  Beta  Gama
0   1.0.4             3  Alpha,Alpha,Alpha      3     0     0
1   1.0.2             3   Alpha,Beta,Alpha      2     1     0
2   1.0.9             3    Alpha,Beta,Gama      1     1     1
```

Or solution with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) is possible, but should be slowier (depends of data, the best test it):

```
s = df['Hardware_type'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df = df.join(s.groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df)
  Version  Cluster_Size      Hardware_type  Alpha  Beta  Gama
0   1.0.4             3  Alpha,Alpha,Alpha      3     0     0
1   1.0.2             3   Alpha,Beta,Alpha      2     1     0
2   1.0.9             3    Alpha,Beta,Gama      1     1     1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks for your help. Nice use of counter here.